# When to write the template angle brackets (<...>)?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Given this example class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack {
    T * data;
    int size;
    int nextIndex;
public:
    Stack(int size = 100);
    Stack(const Stack& stack);
    ~Stack();
    Stack& operator=(const Stack& s);
    void push(const T& t);
    void pop();
    T& top();
    const T& top() const;
    int getSize() const;

    class Full {
    };
    class Empty {
    };
};

template<typename T>
void Stack::push(const T& t) {
    if (nextIndex >= size) {
        throw Full();
    }
    data[nextIndex++] = t;
}
 
template<typename T>
void Stack::pop() {
    if (nextIndex <= 0) {
        throw Empty();
    }
    nextIndex--;
}
```

Is it ok the part of the implementaion of the `push` and `pop` methods?

I don't understand if I need to write `void Stack<T>::push(const T& t)` instead of `void Stack::push(const T& t)` (and the same for the `pop` method).

NOTE: Eclipse (according to C++11) gives me the next error:

> Member declaration not found

because of these lines:

```
void Stack::push(const T& t) { 
void Stack::pop() {
```

Comment: In old compilers it is ok but now you should use `void Stack<T>::`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The part of the implementaion of push method and pop method it's ok? I don't understand if I need to write void Stack::push(const T& t) instead void Stack::push(const T& t) (and the same for pop method).

You need to use

```
template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& t) { ... }

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop() { ... }
```

The name `Stack` is the same as `Stack<T>` inside the class template definition when it is used as a typename. Outside the class template definition, you have to supply the template parameter explicitly.

Comment: According that, it's not so clear why (in contrast to this) I can write `throw Full();` - why it's not gives error and require to write like that: `throw Stack<T>::Full();` ?

Comment: @J.Roe, inside the definition of the member functions of `Stack<T>`, all typenames defined the `Stack<T>` are in scope. Hence, `Full()` is the same as `Stack<T>::Full()`.

Comment: Even if the implementaion of the member function is outside the class?

Comment: @J.Roe, yes. that is indeed the case.

Comment: Just for be certain that I am understand. If for example I am want to call to `Full() ` or `Empty()` in the main, I must write `Stack<T>::Full()` or `Stack<T>::Empty()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Both `push()` and `pop()` are (non-template) *member functions* of the `Stack` *class template*. Since this *class template*, `Stack`, is parameterized by a *type template parameter* (i.e.: `T`), so are those member functions as well.

Therefore, the implementation of those member functions needs a type template parameter:

```
template<typename A>
void Stack<A>::push(const A& t) { ... }

template<typename B>
void Stack<B>::pop() { ... }
```

Note that the name of the template parameter is actually irrelevant (`A` and `B` above).

Note as well that the name of the class template `Stack` not followed by any *template arguments* **inside the body of its definition** is equivalent to the class template with its *template parameter* as the *template argument*, i.e.: `Stack<T>`.