# Rules of thumb of when to include angle brackets <...> for template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, type-parameter

For the class template, what are the rules of thumb to include <type_parameter>? For example, we have the following template class List as a quick example I just coded up:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
public:
    List(); //default constructor
    List(const List& sq); // copy constructor
    List& operator=(const List& lst) // overloaded assignment operator
private:
    T* arr;
    int size;
    List2<T> lst2; // other template class
};

template <class T>
List<T>::List() {
    arr = new List<T>[2]; // allocate memory size of 2
    int size = 0; // number of item currently stored
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& lst) {
    // some implementation

    // making new List
    List<T> temp;
}

template <class T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T>& lst) {
    // some implementation
}
```

I have referenced textbook, searched up online and referring to other questions:
[When to write the template angle brackets (<...>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285264/when-to-write-the-template-angle-brackets)
but I couldn't figure out the rule of thumb when to put the angle brackets. My understanding now is:

- Inside of the template class definitions, no need to put <type_parameter>.
- Put <type_parameter> for other template class object even inside of the class definition.
- Put <type_parameter> for each method as `class_name <type_parameter>::` outside of the class definition.
- How about the method parameter in our example `const List<T>& lst`, do we need  here or si it optional?

Basically, my question is what is the rule of thumb to place <type_parameter>? What if I put  everywhere, would that cause any issues? What is the convention here, etc.

Comment: The answer to the linked question pretty much tells you, doesn't it? *"The name `Stack` is the same as `Stack<T>` inside the class template definition when it is used as a typename. Outside the class template definition, you have to supply the template parameter explicitly."*

Comment: Yes, but how about the method parameter? I assume it is optional as both worked. I just want to know which part is we should place <...> explicitly and which is optional as implicit.